# How to valid a login page using Java and Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my database I have the username = user@javachap.com and password = javachap

If I run the code below, it passes the test although the username and password does not exist in my database.

```
@Test
public void testLogin()
{
  String username="abc";
  String password="123";
  boolean valueFound=false;
// Check the db
try
{
  pstmt=conn.prepareCall("select * from user where USR_EMAIL=? and USD_PASSWORD=?");
  pstmt.setString(1,username);
  pstmt.setString(2,password);
  rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
  valueFound = rs.next();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // report some error
}
```

Comment: There's no assertion in your test, so you need to use `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` and add `assertTrue("Incorrect user/pwd combination", valueFound);`. Also in the catch clause you should probably have a `fail(e.getMessage)` or just make the test throw wxceptions.

Comment: `although the username and password does not exist in my database` - this is out of scope of selenium. you need to write another question as this has nothing to do with selenium.

Comment: Could you please modify my code?

Comment: We could, but testing login by getting checking credentials in database (stored as plain text...) is not a good way of testing login. If you have a web app and want to test login page do it as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class LoginPageTest extends IntegrationTest {

private HtmlUnitDriver driver;

@Before
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException, UnknownHostException{
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    driver.get(System.getProperty("login.url"));
}

@Test
public void testAuthenticationFailureWhenProvidingBadCredentials(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("fakeuser");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("fakepassword");     
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

    assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().endsWith("failed"));
}

@Test
public void testAuthenticationSuccessWhenProvidingCorrectCredentials(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("validuser");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("validpassword");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

    assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().endsWith("/<name_of_webapp>/"));
}

}
```

That's how I do it for example.

EDIT: I just noticed comments. Anyway my code shows how you test the actual login page with Selenium.

Comment: But your code does not test the database, how do i validate that the username and password exist in the database?

Comment: By securing your webapp with anything like Spring Security that queries the database when you login through the login page. The way you want to do it doesn't make sense, you are testing if username and password are in the database while you should be tetsing if login page is working (based on title of your question). You don't need Selenium WebDriver to test database's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Ace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://jars//chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://your login url");

        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("enter username");  
        //pay attention here By.name or By.id, see  the page source properly
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("enter password");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='login']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.name("participant")).sendKeys("BLRFC1");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    }
}
```