# Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException:

Tags: selenium, automation

I am new in Selenium automation testing 
Getting Selenium Error

When I am trying to run below code every time I got error"org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath" I am not sure what xpate will be could some one please help me 
Created Automation test case for Login Application.

**Java:**

```
@Test
    public void enterApplicationCerdentials(String userName, String password) {

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//frameset/frame/html/body/div([@class='tintedBox' and @id='loginBox']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='UserID' and name='UserID'])"))).sendKeys(userName);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Password"))).sendKeys("CSRWHKXESB");
 captureScreen();
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<frameset rows="*, 1">

<frame src="Script/Login.asp?">
#document
<!--Function return the password for the user who logged in through Referral URL. 
          For TAFE user password is not matching as per database value as their URL is dynamic. ENHC0014091
          This function splits the URL of that particular user (8527066229)   only  . -->

<html><head>



<script language="JavaScript">
//<!--
function OnLoad()
{
  setTimeout("CheckFrame()", 4000);
}

function CheckFrame()
{
  with (parent)
  {
    if ((length==0 && document.frmCheck==null) || 
        (length>0 && frames[1].document.frmCheck==null))
    {
      var PathName = window.location.pathname;
      PathName = PathName.substr(0, PathName.substr(1).indexOf("/") + 1);
      location.href = PathName;
    }
  }
}
//-->
</script></head>



<body onload="OnLoad()" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">

<div id="login">
<img border="0" src= vspace="10" style="display: block;">
<div class="tintedBox" id="InfoStoreBox">
<h1>  <a class="boldLink" href="https://infostore.saiglobal.com" target="_parent"><u>InfoStore</u></a> ?</h1>
<p></p>
<p><a class="boldLink" href="https://infostore.saiglobal.com" target="_parent"></a> .</p>
<p>Not only a shop, <a class="boldLink" href="https://infostore.saiglobal.com" target="_parent"></a> </p>
<p><a href="https://infostore.saiglobal.com" target="_parent"></a></p>
</div>

<div class="tintedBox" id="loginBox">
<h1></h1>

<form name="form" action="Login.asp?" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="Autologout" value="false">
  <input type="hidden" name="Division" value="">
  <span class="error"></span>
  <table>
      <tbody><tr>
          <td>User ID</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" id="UserID" name="UserID" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="password" size="30" id="Password" name="Password" value=""></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Last Name/Location</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" id="UserName" name="UserName" value=""></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <br>
  <font color="#d12b2c"><nobr>Your Last Name and Location are now mandatory to access the platform, simply</nobr><br>enter the details in field (e.g. Smith/Perth)</font>
  <br><br>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="SaveLogin" name="SaveLogin" value="SaveLogin"><label for="SaveLogin" id="save">Save my login so you can remember me on my next visit.</label>
  </div>
  <div align="center" style="padding-top:20px">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    <input class="button" type="reset" name="Clear" value="Clear">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="Recognize" value="Remember me?">
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top:20px">
    <nobr>Lost password? Contact your internal Administrator or <a class="boldLink" href="mailto:sales@saiglobal.com?subject=Lost SOL password">our Customer Service</a></nobr>
  </div>
</form>
</div>





</div>
<div id="footer" onmouseover="ShowTime()">©2014 SAI Global</div>
<script>
  function ShowTime()
  {
    var spTime = document.getElementById("footer");
    spTime.innerHTML = "©2014 SAI Global - 20190426 12:25:33.292: 172.20.33.12, 203.27.21.6, 59596377";
  }
</script>


</body></html>
```

**Error:**

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:
>   //frameset/frame/html/body/div([@class='tintedBox' and
>   @id='loginBox']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='UserID' and
>   name='UserID']) (tried for 50 second(s) with 500 milliseconds
>   interval)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
>       at seleniumPages.Page_LoginMyApplication.enterApplicationCerdentials(Page_LoginMyApplication.java:67)
>       at stepDefinitions.StepDefs_DataDrivenLogin.i_login_with_credentials_and(StepDefs_DataDrivenLogin.java:23)
>       at ?.I login with credentials "tomsmith" and "***************"(resources/features/DataDrivenLogin.feature:7) Caused
>   by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector:
>   Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //frameset/frame/html/body/div([@class='tintedBox' and
>   @id='loginBox']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='UserID' and
>   name='UserID']) because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to
>   execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//frameset/frame/html/body/div([@class='tintedBox' and
>   @id='loginBox']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='UserID' and
>   name='UserID'])' is not a valid XPath expression.   (Session info:
>   chrome=73.0.3683.103)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402
>   (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT
>   6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:48' System info: host: 'AP01154W8N', ip:
>   '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_191' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false,
>   browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.46.628402
>   (536cd7adbad73a..., userDataDir: C:\Users\sinham0\AppData\Lo...},
>   cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {debuggerAddress: localhost:65139}, handlesAlerts: true,
>   hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true,
>   locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
>   nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy:
>   normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable:
>   false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false,
>   takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit:
>   0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore,
>   unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.103,
>   webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: 869efd2308887ee98e8d561566b5a606
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//frameset/frame/html/body/div([@class='tintedBox' and
>   @id='loginBox']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='UserID' and
>   name='UserID'])}
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: you can get more information on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832766/A-Small-Java-Script-Using-Selenium-Webdriver link

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22614522/4513879

Comment: @hamesh why you make xpath this much complicated, directly get the userid of that input box.

Comment: @Dhru 'soni I am not getting by using userid. @ Pradnya Bolli @ Pradnya Bolli, HTML Page is devided into Iframe. Could you please some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `TimeoutException` is that the element you are finding is in a frame and you have to switch to that frame. Otherwise, webdriver can't find the element.

First, find the appropriate selector for the `frame` tag. According to your provided HTML I'm constructing the locator.

**XPath:**

```
WebElement loginFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frameset/frame[@src='Script/Login.asp?']"));
```

**CSS Selector:**

```
WebElement loginFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frameset > frame[src='frame_c.htm']"));
```

Try this:

```java
@Test
public void enterApplicationCerdentials(String userName, String password) {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
By frameLocator =  By.xpath("//frameset/frame[@src='Script/Login.asp?']");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//frameset/frame[@src='Script/Login.asp?']")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(frameLocator));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserName"))).sendKeys("UserName");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Password"))).sendKeys("Password");
captureScreen();
}
```